# Backbone + Handlebars -> Loading data in initialize or in render?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I am using BackboneJS with Handlebars for my templates. Works fine at almost any point.
However in one issue it does not work as great as I want.

On loading the page I need some information from the database to load into the page (with handlebars). I am using jQuery's $.ajax() to get the data in a JSON object.

At first I had the $.ajax() running in the initialize method of the Backbone View.
However, sometimes (not always) the data is not turning up in my template.

As a test I now placed the $.ajax() into the render method of the Backbone View.
I didn't see this problem again, but that, unfortunately, does not mean that it isn't there, since it doesn't occur every time.

EDIT: I just had the same issue again, so unfortunately placing it in the render is not helping.

So how should I fix this issue?

Just for the fun of it... here is the code:

```
var OF = OF || {};

OF.ReferrerView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#content',

    initialize: function() {

        if (!OF.address || !OF.address.isValid()) {
             OF.router.navigate('step/1', {trigger: true});
        }

        OF.customerReferrer = OF.customerReferrer || new OF.CustomerReferrer();

    }

    render: function() {

        //save this in that ;)
        var that = this;

        var sendObj = {
            "selectAdult": OF.address.adultTreatment
        };

        //get referrer info
        $.ajax({
            url: "php/fakeAPI/referrer.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: sendObj,
            success: function(data) {
                OF.customerReferrer.referrerTypes = data.referrerTypes;
            }

        });

        OF.template.get('step4-step4', function(data) {

            //set the source en precompile the template
            var htmlSource = $(data).html();
            var template = Handlebars.compile(htmlSource);

            //fill template with object or ''
            var compiled = template(OF.customerReferrer);

            //now place the completely compiled html into the page
            that.$el.html(compiled);

        });

    }
});
```

Comment: is it ok if the view only displayed when the data arrives? i mean promises, and moving the fetching out of the view

Comment: The view is ok only the data is not placed in some fields. I took the assumption this it's because no data is sent to handlebars... so the data must not be there yet. 
As I don't have a promise in there yet, maybe that would work. Don't know how to set this up correctly in the render function though.

Comment: Generally, the render function goes to handle the dynamic data of the page. not used for content management

Comment: So it should be in the initialize, but then I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make ajax requests in views. Preferably don't make them at all, instead using properly configured Model or Collection subclasses, but if you must make manual ajax calls, at least do it in a model. Then have your view bind to sync/change events on the model and render appropriately.